# ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts:63:11 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'tz'

Tags: angular, global, moment-timezone, persian-calendar, jalali-calendar

I tried to install ( "ngx-persian-datepicker": "^0.1.3" ) on my angular boilerplate framework.
but wen i run "npm start" , I get this error.

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts:63:11 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'tz'.
63     const tz: MomentTimezone;
             ~~

  ../node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts:73:11
    73     const tz: MomentTimezone;
                 ~~
    'tz' was also declared here.
../node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts:73:11 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'tz'.

73     const tz: MomentTimezone;
             ~~

  ../node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts:63:11
    63     const tz: MomentTimezone;
                 ~~
    'tz' was also declared here.
```

I tried differenet versions of @types/moment-timezone but i did not work.
Also, I tried different modules like "@angular-persian/material-date-picker" but i get this error again.
I cant understand what this error is for.
can anyone help me?